# Fetch data to select tag from oracle database

Tags: javascript, php, html, oracle-sqldeveloper

```js
function display_docs()
{
  global $con;
  $query="select doctor_name from doctors";
  $result=oci_parse($con,$query);
  oci_execute($result);
  while($row=oci_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $doctor_name=$row['DOCTOR_NAME'];
    echo '<option value="'.$doctor_name.'">'.$doctor_name.'</option>';
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="doctor" class="form-control" >
  <?php display_docs();?>
</select>
```

I have problems with my code, I don't know where is a bug, I can't see the result in the select tag. 
Expected output: I must take all information from SQL developer where I am saving data about doctors and show it in the select tag.
My output: nothing in the select tag.

I am calling javascript function into HTML code

I have no problems with connecting to the database

Comment: You can try `var_dump`.First,  ensure `$result` has the data you need, you can use var_dump to debug. Then, ensure the `$row` has the key `DOCTOR_NAME` still by var_dump.Happy debugging.

Comment: I did it and it gives me right data, but I still can't see this data on the page.

Comment: perhaps browser cache?

Comment: I did it also, it didn't help

Comment: Interesting, press ctrl + U, then search and check the options if exists, if so maybe some javascripts hide the select,if not, there should be something wrong in the echo function.